# Dynamic table name for INSERT INTO query

Tags: postgresql, function, insert, plpgsql, dynamic-queries

I am trying to figure out how to write an `INSERT INTO` query with table name and column name of the source as parameter.

For starters I was just trying to parametrize the source table name. I have written the following query. For now I am declaring and assigning the value of the variable `tablename` directly, but in actual example it would come from some other source/list. The target table has only one column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    tablename text;
BEGIN
   tablename := 'Table_1';
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO "Schemaname"."targettable"
   SELECT "Col_A"
   FROM "schemaname".'
   ||quote_ident(tablename);
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Although the query runs without any error no changes are reflected at the target table. On running the query I get the following output.

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (execution time: 296 ms; total time: 296 ms)

I want the changes to be reflected at the target table. I don't know how to resolve the problem.

Comment: If you have multiple tables with the same schema, such that they contain the same "sort" of data, that's usually an indication that they ought to be a single table with an additional column to contain the data that is probably, currently, embedded as part of the table *names*. I.e. if you were modelling an organization, you almost certainly shouldn't have `maleEmployees` and `femaleEmployees` tables.

Comment: Is it possible that `"schemaname"."Table_1"` has zero rows? What is the output of: `SELECT count("Col_A") FROM "schemaname"."Table_1";`

Answer (score 1):

#### Audited code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
   RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl text := 'Table_1';  -- or 'table_1'?
BEGIN       
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO schemaname.targettable(column_name)
   SELECT  "Col_A"
   FROM    schemaname.' || quote_ident(_tbl);  -- or "Schemaname"?
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Always use an explicit target list for persisted `INSERT` statements.
- You can assign variables at declare time.
- It's a wide-spread folly to use **double-quoted identifiers** to preserve otherwise illegal spelling. You have to keep double-quoting the name for the rest of its existence. One or more of those errors seem to have crept into your code: `"Schemaname"` or `"schemaname"`? `Table_1` or `"Table_1"`?

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- When you provide an identifier like a table name as `text` parameter and escape it with `quote_ident()`, it is ***case sensitive***!
  Identifiers in SQL code are cast to lower case unless double-quoted. But `quote-ident()` (which you *must* use to defend against SQL injection) preserves the spelling you provide with double-quotes where necessary.

#### Function with parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_tbl text)
   RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN       
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO schemaname.targettable(column_name)
   SELECT  "Col_A"
   FROM    schemaname.' || quote_ident(_tbl);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT foo('tablename');  -- tablename is case sensitive
```

There are other ways:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)